# Request.IsAuthenticated return true when logged in into my other application

Tags: c#, authentication, model-view-controller

I am working on 2 mvc application. I am using Request.IsAuthenticated for authenticate user. When i login into one application other application also logged in automatically.

I am using cookies for login.

```
    int TimeOut = 525600;                            
    var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket("UserName", true, TimeOut);                                
    string Encrypt = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);                                
    var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, Encrypt);                               
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(TimeOut);                               
    cookie.HttpOnly = true;  
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

please give your valuable suggestion to solve this error.

Comment: If it's the same domain (as in mywebsite.com) (or a subdomain) the browser will send the cookie with every request. So effectively one cookie = on login

Answer (score 1):

It's happens when using same machine key in web.config file. I have changed machine key and it has solved.